# python/ how do i draw a circle when a certain key is pressed with pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

mainui.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'mainmDcRLP.ui'
##
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.15.2
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(108, 84)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 75, 23))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 108, 21))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\uc88c\ud45c\uc5f4\uae30", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

ui.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'untitled1edNQgt.ui'
##
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.15.2
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPixmap

class MyLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        self.ellipses = []
        super(MyLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.radius = 0
        self.center = None


    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        if self.center:
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
            painter.setPen(QPen(QColor('white'), 3, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawEllipse(self.center, self.radius, self.radius)

    


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if not Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(1253, 794)
        self.label = MyLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 1031, 781))
        self.label.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(u"volcano1_3.png"))
        self.label_14 = QLabel(Form)
        self.label_14.setObjectName(u"label_14")
        self.label_14.setGeometry(QRect(1050, 20, 56, 12))
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily(u"Arial")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_14.setFont(font)
        self.label_14.setStyleSheet(u"color: rgb(85, 85, 127);")
        self.current_x = QLineEdit(Form)
        self.current_x.setObjectName(u"current_x")
        self.current_x.setGeometry(QRect(1090, 38, 41, 20))
        self.current_y = QLineEdit(Form)
        self.current_y.setObjectName(u"current_y")
        self.current_y.setGeometry(QRect(1180, 38, 41, 20))
        self.label_15 = QLabel(Form)
        self.label_15.setObjectName(u"label_15")
        self.label_15.setGeometry(QRect(1140, 40, 31, 16))
        self.label_16 = QLabel(Form)
        self.label_16.setObjectName(u"label_16")
        self.label_16.setGeometry(QRect(1050, 40, 31, 16))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Form", None))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label_14.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"\ud604\uc7ac \uc88c\ud45c", None))
        self.current_y.setText("")
        self.label_15.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Y\uc88c\ud45c", None))
        self.label_16.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"X\uc88c\ud45c", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from ui import Ui_Form
from mainui import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mainui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.mainui.setupUi(self)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size()) 
        self.mainui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.testtest)
        self.display = MainDisplay()

    def testtest(self):
        
        self.display.show()

class MainDisplay(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ellipses = []
        self.total = None
        super().__init__()
        self.display = Ui_Form()
        self.display.setupUi(self)
        self.display.label.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.display.label.mouseMoveEvent = self.getpos
        self.display.label.mousePressEvent = self.click
        self.display.label.keyPressEvent = self.key1


    def getpos(self, event):
        self.x = event.x()
        self.y = event.y()
        self.total = event.pos()

        self.display.current_x.setText(str(self.x))
        self.display.current_y.setText(str(self.y))


    def click(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.ellipses.append(event.pos())
            self.update()

        '''     
        print (event)
        self.display.label.center = event.pos()
        print (event.pos())
        self.display.label.radius = 20
        self.display.label.update()
        '''

    def key1(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_1:

            self.display.label.center = self.total
            self.display.label.radius = 20
            self.display.label.update()
        
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_2:

            self.display.label.center = self.total
            self.display.label.radius = 20
            self.display.label.update()
        
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_3:

            self.display.label.center = self.total
            self.display.label.radius = 20
            self.display.label.update()
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = MainWindow()
    myWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

image used in ui.py
[image: volcano1_3.png]

so main.py is the main source. once i run it, it opens a window with a button (mainui.py). if i click the button, it opens another window (ui.py) with an image i attached. what i want to do is i want to draw a circle with a number in it when a certain key is pressed (in this case, its 1,2 and 3)
so if i press number 1 over the image, it will draw a circle with number 1 in it.
the code i have right now draws a circle when a key is pressed but without number in it and it shares the same circle with all the 1,2,3 key pressing and i want to make it look like below.

(each key press event should have one circle drawn)

[image]

can anyone tell me how to achieve this?